# Rect relative to Render Texture

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having a hard time figuring out how to find correct rect that represents a ui element area. I get the Ui element RectTransform. I tried to use it directly, using a function and RectTransformUtility, but nothing seems to wok.
Here is the code.

```
    RenderTexture.active = scr;

    //adjust rect position
    //Rect rect = RectUtils.RectTransformToScreenSpace (rectTransform);
    int width = System.Convert.ToInt32 (rect.width);
    int height = System.Convert.ToInt32 (rect.height);

    // Create a texture the size of the screen, RGB24 format
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

    RenderTexture.active = scr;
    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0);

    tex.Apply();

    RenderTexture.active = null;

    // Encode texture into PNG
    byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    //todo destroy the texture
    Object.Destroy (tex);
    // For testing purposes, also write to a file in the project folder
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
```

I tried to create rect in different ways like:

Methood 1:

```
    Vector2 size = Vector2.Scale(transform.rect.size, transform.lossyScale);
    Rect rect = new Rect(transform.position.x, Screen.height - transform.position.y, size.x, size.y);
    rect.x -= (transform.pivot.x * size.x);
    rect.y -= ((1.0f - transform.pivot.y) * size.y);
    return rect;
```

Method 2:

```
    Vector2 temp = rectT.transform.position;
    var startX = temp.x - width/2;
    var startY = temp.y - height/2;

    var tex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    tex.ReadPixels (new Rect(startX, startY, width, height), 0, 0);
```

I am using Unity 5.5 Mac version.

when i pass to ReadPixels new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height) i see the whole RenderTexture in its defined dimensions 1920x1080

I want to use this as a baker of UI elements as I am having performance issue, and definitively no other solution to implement the required behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also struggled with this problem. Here's how I solved it.
First we need the position of RectTransform in screen and for this I used RectTransformUtility. Then since the rect x, y is the starting point at left bottom (note: in GUI x, y is at left top) we subtract respectively the half of width and height.

```
        Vector2 rectPos = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint (Camera.main, rectTransform.position);

        float startX = rectPos.x - width / 2;
        float startY = rectPos.y - height / 2;
        Rect screenRect = new Rect (startX, startY, width, height);
```

Note: width height should be integer.

Edit: The above solution when we use Screen overlay and change resolution from standard to any other do not work. Even if I used the lossyscale I could not get consistent behavior.
One method of RecTransformUtility is really helpful for this situation (WorldToScreenPoint).

```
    Vector3[] bounds = new Vector3[4];

    rectTransform.GetWorldCorners (bounds);

    Vector2 rectPos = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint (camera, rectTransform.position);

    Vector2 minPosition = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint (camera, bounds[0]);
    Vector2 maxPosition = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint (camera, bounds[2]);

    Vector2 size = maxPosition - minPosition;

    float startX = rectPos.x - size.x / 2;
    float startY = rectPos.y - size.y / 2;

    return new Rect (startX, startY,  size.x, size.y);
```